# $\lambda \in \rho(A)$ and $|\lambda - \mu| < \Vert R_\lambda \Vert^{-1}$ then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\lambda - \mu)^n R_\lambda ^{n+1} = (\mu - A)^{-1}$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, spectral-theory, markov-process

This is a remark from Ethier-Kurtz Markov Processes. I don't understand why the sum below is a bounded linear operator and in fact $(\mu - A)^{-1}$. Also, how does this imply that $\rho(A)$ is open? I would greatly appreciate any explanation. Above this remark, there is the resolvent identity 
$$R_\lambda R_\mu = R_\mu R_\lambda = (\lambda - \mu)^{-1}(R_\mu - R_\lambda).$$

Let $A$ be a closed linear operator on $L$. If $\lambda \in \rho(A)$, the resolvent set of $A$, and $|\lambda - \mu| < \Vert R_\lambda \Vert^{-1}$, where $R_\lambda = (\lambda I-A)^{-1}$, then 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\lambda - \mu)^n R_\lambda ^{n+1}$$ defines a bounded linear operator that is in fact $(\mu - A)^{-1}$. In particular, this implies that $\rho(A)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @ "How does this imply $\varrho(A)$ is open? You pick a $\lambda \in \varrho(A)$ and a $\mu$ very close to it and show that it is also in $\varrho(A)$, as you can find an explicit formula for the inverse. You might also want to have a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3579939/545914) of mine where the above proof is outlined in a bit more detail.

Comment: Also why should $\rho(A) \subset \mathbb{R}$? Shouldn't it thus be $\mathbb{C}$ in the last sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Τhe operator $T=\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (\lambda-\mu)^n R_\lambda^{n+1}$ is a bounded linear operator. Indeed this a Newman series, of the form $\sum a_nR^n$, and convergence is guaranteed whenever 
$$
\|R\| \limsup_{n\to\infty}|a_n|^{1/n}<1.
$$ 
It suffices to show that $(\mu-A)Tx=x$, for all $x$ is our Banach space.

We have that
$$
(\mu-A)Tx=\big((\lambda-A)-(\lambda-\mu)\big)\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (\lambda-\mu)^n R_\lambda^{n+1}x \\=\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (\lambda-\mu)^{n} (\lambda-A)R_\lambda^{n+1}x-\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (\lambda-\mu)^{n+1} R_\lambda^{n+1}x \\=\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (\lambda-\mu)^{n} R_\lambda^{n}x-\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (\lambda-\mu)^{n+1} R_\lambda^{n+1}x=(\lambda-\mu)^0R_\lambda^0x=x.
$$
Note that $(\lambda-A)R^{n+1}_\lambda=(\lambda-A)(\lambda-A)^{-1}R^{n}_\lambda=R^{n}_\lambda.$

Comment: Can you show why $T$ is bounded? Also in the second equality, how do we justify exchanging the infinite sum and $\lambda - A$?